$\int_{[0,1]}P_r\hspace{0.1 cm}dm = 1$ where $P_r$ is the Poisson kernel
Given $r\in (0,1)$, we define the Poisson kernel by
$$
P_r = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty r^{|n|}e^{2\pi inx}.
$$
My instructor said that we have
$$
\int_{[0,1]}P_r\hspace{0.1 cm} dm = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty r^{|n|}\int_{[0,1]}e^{2\pi inx}\hspace{0.1 cm}dm = 1
$$
due to the Fubini's theorem.
I remember that Fubini's theorem is about integration on a product space (I didn't learn analysis well, I might miss something), so I failed to see how the equality follows from Fubini's theorem.
I also don't know how to compute the integral. I know that we can take the sum out if it is a finite sum, but in this case we are dealing with an infinite series.
Any help is appreciated!

Fubini’s theorem has to do with the order of integration, and you need to consider the product measure, as a sum is more or less an integral, I assume they are citing Fubini to justify the swapping of the sum and the integral. Then we have that the integral $\int_0^1e^{2\pi inx} dx$ is always $0$ unless $n=0$ in which case the integral is $1$. Thus, you only pick up the $n=0$ term of the sum which is how you end up with $1$.

Probanly the easiest way to see this is hidden in the following two problems.

Prove that uniform convergence of $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ implies $$\int_E f_n(x)\,dx\to\int_E f(x)\,dx$$

For fixed $r$, show that the series defining $P_r(x)$ converges uniformly.



Recall the following version of Fubini's theorem:

Theorem. (Fubini) Let $(X,\mathscr A,\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathscr B,\nu)$ be $\sigma$-finite measure spaces, and let $f:X\times Y\to\mathbb{C}$ be $\mathscr A\times\mathscr B$-measurable and $\mu\times\nu$-integrable. Then for $\mu$-almost every $x\in X$, the section $Y\to\mathbb{C}, y\mapsto f(x,y)$ is $\nu$-integrable, and for $\nu$-almost every $y\in Y$, the section $X\to\mathbb{C}, x\mapsto f(x,y)$ is $\mu$-integrable, and
$$\int_{X\times Y}f\,\mathrm{d}(\mu\times\nu)=\int_X\int_Yf(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}\nu(y)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x)=\int_Y\int_Xf(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y)\,\mathrm{d}\nu(x).$$

In your case, we can take the measure spaces to be $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure and $\mathbb{Z}$ with counting measure. Observing that integration with respect to counting measure corresponds to infinite summation, we can check integrability by observing that
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_0^1\left\lvert r^{\lvert n\rvert}e^{2\pi int}\right\rvert\,\mathrm{d}t=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}r^{\lvert n\rvert}<\infty$$
as $r\in(0,1)$. The function $[0,1]\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R},(t,n)\mapsto r^{\lvert n\rvert}e^{2\pi int}$ thus satisfies the conditions of Fubini's theorem, and so
$$\int_0^1P_r(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^1\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}r^{\lvert n\rvert}e^{2\pi int}\,\mathrm{d}t=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}r^{\lvert n\rvert}\underbrace{\int_0^1e^{2\pi int}\,\mathrm{d}t}_{=\delta_{i0}}=r^{\lvert0\rvert}=1.$$
